# Call C# webservice function in HTML page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, c#-4.0

How do I call a C# webservice function in HTML page using Javascript? I have been trying with the following code, but my Javascript function is not even communicating to the webservice.

**Javascript Function:**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var iCallID;
    function getEmail()
    {
        iCallID=document.getElementById("email").value;
        service.useService("http://localhost:1551/MyWebSite/MyWebService.asmx?wsdl", "GetDateTimeService");
        alert(iCallID);

        service.GetDateTimeService.callService("sendEmail",iCallID);
        alert(event.result.value);
    }
</script>
```

**C# Webservices**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for MyWebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public MyWebService()
    {
        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string sendEmail(string EmailID)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("some-email@gmail.com", "password");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        MailMessage mailmsg = new MailMessage();
        mailmsg.From = new MailAddress(EmailID);
        mailmsg.To.Add("some-email@gmail.com");
        mailmsg.Subject = "test";
        mailmsg.Body = "test mail";

        client.Send(mailmsg);

        return "Email Sent Successfully";
    }
}
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug the problem?

Comment: doing it in VS 2010...by putting alert pop-up box,i am checking it step by step..

Comment: Is there any way you can test exactly what part is failing? Maybe you could get the web service to write to a file or standard output so that you know if it is working but not sending the email, for example.

Comment: no i am not using jquery...i am just struggling to call the webservice method..yeah my websevice is working fine...

Comment: @puneeth - just as an FYI, that whole serial downvoting thing? Yeah - StackOverflow has a system in place that detects that, and deals with the people who do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it:

Add a href to the page and some js at the bottom:

```
<a href="javascript:SendEmailJs()">Send mail!</a>
//Other logic
<script type="text/javascript>
function SendEmailJs(){
    var url = '@(Url.Action("SendEmail"))';
    var emailId = document.getElementById("email").value;
    url += "/?EmailID=" + emailId;
    $.get(url, function(data){
        alert(data.tostring);
    }
}
</script>
```